# Mongoose wont connect to MongoDB on Heroku (Works on local dev env)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I get the following error message when trying to connect my NodeJS Express app to my MongoDB server hosted on Heroku. It works fine on my local dev env.

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-hl87n.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cluster0-shard-00-00-hl87n.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
```

I am getting the connect string the following way.

```
const server = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const database = process.env.MONGODB_DB;
const user = process.env.MONGODB_USER;
const password = process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD;

mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${user}:${password}@${server}/${database}`, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

The enviroment variables are active on my Heroku instance, I confirmed this by doing heroku config, and also with a console log that correctly prints out all of the above information.

Any idea what could be pointing to this issue, Im out of trails to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb Cloud requires that you Whitelist the IP that the connections are coming from. Unfourtunatly Heroku doesn't supply you with an IP address so you need to allow access from all IP addresses if you want it to work.

Incase anyone else falls upon this issue that was the fix.